# Error when accessing incorrect property in a component that is not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this component that takes in a component and renders the children if the condition is met,

```
const Can = ({ condition, children }) => (condition ? children : null);

const obj = { a: 2 };
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Can condition>Condition true</Can>
      <Can>
        {console.log('Inside false condition')}
        <p>False condition {obj.b.x}</p> {/* b.x will throw error */}
      </Can>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is bound to fail, but I dont understand at what point does react parse its content?
why does the console.log execute if the `condition` is false?

This error doesnt occur when calling the children as a function

```
const Can = ({ condition, children }) => (condition ? children() : null);

const obj = { a: 2 };
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Can>
        {() => <p>False condition {obj.b.x}</p>}
      </Can>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: because ```console.log``` is not a child.

Answer (score 0):

React parses its content into Javascript at compile-time. So what happens is, after the compilation, when the DOM construction begins all the components are mounted one-by-one. When, a `Can` component is to be mounted it's children are processed and passed as `children` props. During that processing, the `console.log` statement gets executed, and you see the output. Also, the error comes, during this processing only when `obj.b.x` is not found.

In the second case, when you pass children as a function, the JSX returns a function, which only gets executed when the condition is true, since the condition is false in your case, so no processing of paragraph tag and hence no error comes up.

Check the logging of children component [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-frost-k7gnf), you will get a greater idea.